# Where can I find user friendly Release Management tools?

Tags: version-control, user-interface, information-management

I am having a hard time when trying to find a free or commercial tool that offers a dashboard where IT managers, DBAs and developers can easily see which **releases versions are currently installed in our customers**.

This user friendly tool could be a webpage just to give more visibility to everyone about the current deployed versions. I am also thinking about creating a webpage for this purpose which would pull from database information like *customer name*, *software name* and *current release version*.

Here is an idea of what I am looking for:

[image]

Where can I find more tools like this?

Comment: Does it need to connect to the customers' computers to check for versions? Can you force all customers to install an agent tool?

Comment: No it does not need to connect to remote computers. I would like to enter the information myself: `Customer 1 - Software A - Current release 1.0.2`

Comment: @JuniorM If you use a [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) in your organisation you should be able to get that information easily and perhaps there's already the functionality of displaying such data on a web page.

Comment: If there is a CRM, it could be an answer. Which ones are available for customization?